# How to display images from an xml file in UI Image View

Tags: ios4, xcode4.2

i have an xml file , there are number of images i want to display them
 in a **"Image View"** and the **"Image View"** will be in scroll view as u
 scroll the images should keep loading .  i am having difficulty in
 coding that ,any help would be helpful

Comment: U r getting url of image in xml?

Comment: yes there are url of images in xml .

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you [Load image to a tableView from URL iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565123/load-image-to-a-tableview-from-url-iphone-sdk)

Try to download lazy loading application code and implement that in your project.

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) for application Lazy loading.

Comment: how can i load the images on a scrollview ? i want to extract the url from xml and load it on image view

Comment: You will understand if you will try to understand the code of apple's program.

Comment: thanks ,i will look into it and refer back if i have a problem in executing