# Xcode parsing RSS XML with images issue

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xml-parsing, uiimageview, nsdata

I am trying to parse text with images in the UITableView and I can only see the text for every line but I can't see the images.

Here is my code;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.anaTablo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


    UILabel *textBaslik = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    UIImage *imagePic = (UIImage *) [cell viewWithTag:7];

    textBaslik.text =[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    imagePic.images = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

but it didn't works and after searching I have tried this to;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    UILabel *textBaslik = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    UIImage *imagePic = (UIImage *) [cell viewWithTag:7];

    textBaslik.text =[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", imageArray];

    NSData *bgImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str1];

    UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithData:bgImageData];

    imagePic = [img1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell
```

}

Am I doing something wrong? I am kind new to Xcode

Thanks from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check you code and i change the following

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", imageArray];
NSData *bgImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str1];
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithData:bgImageData];

imagePic = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.imageView.image=imagePic;
```

in the delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Now a new error appear, check it

Comment: My problem was this too    

    NSString *trimmedString = [imageLink.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 3):

Check this tutorial about parsing RSS with XMLParses, it works perfectly.
[Wiki XML parse data](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)

You should check this sample code using  TBXML framework 
[TBXML parser](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML)

Comment: My RSS is working fine and I can see all the texts in the UItableView but I couldn't parse the picture that is my problem. Thanks for the link but it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: are you getting a url of the image? check this link that will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565123/load-image-to-a-tableview-from-url-iphone-sdk

Comment: you have to download the images from the url in a asyncronous way(it´s better).try the apple sample Lazy tableviews, it´s a good point to start http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html

Comment: Thank you Aitul for you help but this is difficult for mw is there easier way? I could share my code with you mine is very simple code.

Comment: Here you have an easy example to undertand it:http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-tutorial-image-cache-and-loading-thumbnails-using-mknetworkkit/ please vote my up if the answer are interesting

Comment: Thank you Aitul for your help but it is not my answer and I left a vote for you.