# AFNetworking and local image URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm trying to get an image from a local url using AFNetworking with this code:

```
    NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:@"My Image.png"]];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder Image.png"] success:nil failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%s: setImageWithURLRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    }];
```

and I am getting this error:

```
NSErrorFailingURLKey=/var/mobile/Applications/6D878789-640E-4299-AA72-45D49211492D/Documents/My Image.png, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x15df8b60 "unsupported URL"}
```

How can I do this with AFNetworking?

Comment: Just a thought. Did you try *[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]* method?

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[cell.imageView setImageWithUrl:url];

Answer (score 0):

Try not setting the success block to nil and use this code:

```
[cell.myImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
{
            weakimageView.image = image;

          } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
          {
             //Deal with failure
          }];
```

Comment: After thinking about it again, if the image is local, why you are using AFNetworking for this? Just place the image in the cell.

Comment: I'm searching for a solution because without the AFNetworking the collection view gets lag.

Comment: @user3164474 to resolve lag you need GCD's lazy loading

Comment: @user3164474 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668160/asynchronous-downloading-of-images-for-uitableview-with-gcd

Comment: Property 'loader' not found. Can u tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works perfectly fine,..

Download UIImageView+webcache.h and .m file and add to your project.

link is here [https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView%2BWebCache.h](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h)

```
NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:@"My Image.png"]];

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder Image.png"]];
```

or using Blocks,

```
NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:@"My Image.png"]];

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder Image.png"] success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached) {
        <#code#>  ---> if success
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        <#code#>  ---> if failure
    }];
```

Comment: Invalid url. I'm trying with a local url.