# Loading and Caching Images Asynchronously in UITableviewCell using GCD

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am displaying images in `UITableview` using json data and get images. But the data is displayed in `UITablevewcells`. But images are not displyed. It will take time and after images are displayed. so I want to displayed the images for my uitableview asynchronously using GCD.But I have no idea of asynchronous GCD Concept.Please give me any idea how to applicable asynchronous GCD concept in my coding. please give me guidance any body.
This is my code.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{    
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
   NSError *err;
   NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"response is %@",strResponse);
   dit=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
   NSArray *arrResults = [dit valueForKey:@"classifieds_mst"];
   listOfObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

for(dictRes in arrResults) {
 Attributes *at = [[Attributes alloc]init];      
at.classimage=[dictRes valueForKey:@"image_name"];
[listOfObjects addObject:at];
 }

[tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
     }
    classifiedimage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:classifiedimage];
     NSString *str;
    str=att.classimage;
    if(str==nil) {
        classifiedimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    } else{
    url=@"My url";
     NSString *addurl=[url stringByAppendingString:str];
    classifiedimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:addurl];
     }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Any body give me guidance please

Comment: please refer this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668160/asynchronous-downloading-of-images-for-uitableview-with-gcd?rq=1

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, for asynchronously loading images in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, Here I am getting the url of images and use the lazy loading.

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString *imageStr=[@"urlLink" stringByAppendingString:[populerPostImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        [cell.myImgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nopic.png"]];
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response.But i got error this line of code [cell.myImgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nopic.png"]];  The error message will display like this no visible interface for UIImageview declares the selector setImageWithUrl:placeholiderImage."

Comment: Actually I have created a custom cell class and myImgView declared in that class.You can use cell.imageView and also use your own image as the placeholderImage not nopic.png.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Lazy loading concept for loading images. for this refer below link: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: thanks for your response.But please give me any solutions. you send the github code is very difficult to understand.Please give me solution based on my code.

Comment: you can just add SDWebImage folder in your application and import #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h" this and put below line of code       inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method: 
                                                          [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your image path"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Comment: I think you should have reputation to me because I have suggested to you for the Lazy Loading concept and also provided you the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load and cache your images, you can use [APSmartStorage](https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage).
It supports downloading, memory and disk cache with automatically purge on memory warning.
Works like a charm:)