# Geting multiple Images from Url In ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiimageview, arrays

i have code to display a single image from json array data in a UIImageView.
i want to display all images in multiple UIImageViews.
plz suggest me how to loop images to display all.
json array data link:

Here's code from my app

```
 NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php"];

    NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *json=(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];



    NSLog(@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSString *imageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:0]];

                NSURL * urlone=[NSURL URLWithString:imageString];

    NSData *datanew =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlone];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:datanew]];

    testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f, 200.0f)];

    [testView addSubview:imageView];

    [self.view addSubview:testView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php"];

NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *json=(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%d",[json count]);

NSLog(@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:0]);
NSString *imageString;
for (int i=0; i<[json count]; i++) {
     imageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:i]];
    [arr addObject:imageString];
}

NSLog(@"%@",arr);
// NSString *imageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:0]];

 NSURL * urlone=[NSURL URLWithString:imageString];

 NSData *datanew =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlone];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:datanew]];

UIView *  testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f, 200.0f)];

[testView addSubview:imageView];

[self.view addSubview:testView];
```

Comment: Could you explain what in the code you have posted is an answer to the problem happening here, so that the user and future readers can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

After parsing JSON response use follow code

```
UIScrollView *testView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
for(int i=0; i<[json count]; i++){
NSLog(@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:i]);
NSString *imageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:i]];
NSURL * urlone=[NSURL URLWithString:imageString];
NSData *datanew =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlone];*
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,i*480,320,480)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:datanew]];
[testView addSubview:imageView];
}
[self.view addSubView:testView];
```

*Note: Now you are going with Synchronous Request to download & load images in the view. It is not a good approach. Use Asynchronous requests for downloading images and loading them.

Find the following URL for asynchronous image downloading

[Asynchronous downloading of images for UITableView with GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668160/asynchronous-downloading-of-images-for-uitableview-with-gcd)

Answer (score 0):

you can get an image dictionary into array like this, into data object
Suppose i have PostClubDC class with posDC obj

```
 for(NSDictionary *returnDicto in dataArray)
        {
            PostClubDC *postDC = [[PostClubDC alloc] init];
            NSDictionary * returnDict = [returnDicto objectForKey:@"club_info"] ;
            postDC.postID = [[returnDict objectForKey:@"Id"]integerValue];
            postDC.postName = [returnDict objectForKey:@"name"];
            postDC.postImage = [returnDict objectForKey:@"image"];

            [yourDataArray addObject:postDC];
        }
```