# table view scrolling issue.I just want to display a large amount of images ; but it slows down table scrolling.How can it perform better?

Tags: ios, image, web-services, grand-central-dispatch

Grand Central Dispatch

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    url_Img1=@"http://kiascenehai.pk/assets/uploads/event-images/50x50-thumb/";

    url_Img2=userObj.event_dpURL;

    url_Img_FULL = [url_Img1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:url_Img2];

    [arr addObject:url_Img_FULL];

    NSUserDefaults * userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userDefault setObject:userObj.event_dpURL forKey:@"dpURL"];

    [userDefault synchronize];

     result = [userDefault objectForKey:@"dpURL"];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     [tableData addObjectsFromArray:retrievedData];

     [table reloadData];
     });

    });

}
```

Comment: You need to add your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code here

Comment: but row at index path can not be crated here ; as its another method like : -(void)repaint:(NSMutableArray *)retrievedData
{}

Comment: show the cell for rowatindex method

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    
    User *user = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];
    });
                    });
    return cell;
}

Comment: Where is called your `dispatch_async`in your code ? Call your dataWithContentsOfURL: asynchronously, see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668366/2571566

Comment: in the cell for row at index path    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arr[indexPath.row]]]]];

        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            SampleTableCell * cell = (SampleTableCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            //  sets the image at the main thred of cell :::::
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking Library for fast loading image from web.

You can get this library from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking link